# removeClass not removing animation classes on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
(function removeAnimation() {
    var $window = $(window),
    $html = $('html');
    if ($window.width() < 600) {
        alert("working");
        $('.animated').removeClass('animated');
        $('.slideInLeft').removeClass('slideInLeft');
        $('.fadeIn').removeClass('fadeIn');
        $('.fadeOut').removeClass('fadeOut');
        $('.bounce').removeClass('bounce');
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hero-content">

  <div class="hero-text">
   <h1 class="animated slideInLeft">Ryan Klotz</h1>
   <h4 class="animated slideInLeft">Front-End Web Developer</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="animated fadeIn">
   <div class="animated fadeOut">
      <span 
          class="animated bounce glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down" aria-label="Scroll Down">                   </span>
     </div>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

I am trying to remove animations from the content when the user is mobile (it seems to be causing a strange bug). I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong with jQuery. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: Does the alert still fire?

Comment: added the html, and yes the alert fires!

Comment: Odd. I can get that code to remove classes: http://jsfiddle.net/ok03b59j/1/

Comment: I have a feeling OP just has a typo in his source code. The snippet here doesn't work because it lacks jQuery, so there's no real way to tell

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working with changing my code around a bit:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {      
    var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)");

    if (isMobile.matches) {
        $('.animated').removeClass('animated');
        $('.slideInLeft').removeClass('slideInLeft');
        $('.glyphicon').remove();    
    }
 });
```

Thank you to everyone commenting!